# Excel add-in focus issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel, add-in

I'm developing an **add-in** for Microsoft **Excel**. I have a button which creates a **form** for the additional parameters input. I'd like the user to be able to select a range as one of the additional parameters (like choosing a range for a diagram or formula). The point is I cannot find out how to focus the active sheet while leaving the form shown.

I've tried to send the form the active sheet by means of *Excel.Worksheet activeSheet = Application.ActiveSheet* and then activate it when the event occurs, however that didn't work.
I've also tried to send the owner to the form using *Show()* method, but it's also incorrect for add-ins.

Is there a simple way to deactivate the form, choose a range and then activate the form again?